# Upload blob on server with ajax

Tags: ajax, file-upload, twitter-bootstrap, blob

Can anyone tell me how I can store a blob on the server with an ajax call?
I have tried many things but none of them work. And I cannot find any good information about this.

This is where I want to send the blob

```
class Ajax extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('form_helper');
    $this->load->library('tank_auth');

}

public function saverecording()
{
    $status = "";
    $msg = "";
    $file_element_name = 'komaan';
    if ($status != "error")
    {
          $config['upload_path'] = '../../upload/audio/recordings/';
          $config['allowed_types'] = 'wav';
          $this->load->library('upload', $config);
          if (!$this->upload->do_upload($file_element_name))
          {
             $status = 'error';
             $msg = $this->upload->display_errors('', '');
             echo '<script>
             console.log("this is not working");</script>';
          }
          else
          {
             $data = $this->upload->data();
             echo '<script>
             console.log("this is ");</script>';
             //$file_id = $this->files_model->insert_file($data['file_name'], $_POST['title']);
          }
          @unlink($_FILES[$file_element_name]);
       }
}
```

**NEW EDIT**: Thanks for your patience, I'm pretty new with web development. I figured out what the problem is. As I said I get a blob file from javascript code:

```
recorder.exportWAV(function(blob) {
            console.log(blob);
            $('userfile').val(blob);
            $.ajaxFileUpload({
            url :  "../ajax/saverecording/", 
            secureuri      :false,
            fileElementId  :'userfile',
                dataType : blob.type,
                data: blob,
                success: function(data, status) {
                    if(data.status != 'error')
                        alert("hoera!");
                    alert(data.msg);
                }
            });
        });
```

The $('userfile').val(blob); gives me a "Uncaught Error: InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11 " Why?

Thanks

Katrijne

Comment: Perhaps show the work you have done and identify where you are having specific problems.

Comment: @MikeBrant Hi I added my code.

Comment: Well it seems that by your usage of `$this` that this is part of a method of a larger class.  You might want to include some of the pertinent parts of that class code.  If the upload is happening correctly, you can simply remove the javascript portion of your question to help keep people focused on where the problem actually lies.

Comment: Hi changed it again. Thanks for you reactions btw, I'm quite desperate. Do you think it is possible to send a blob with ajax? The answer below says not.

Comment: Well again, there is not really enough context.  It looks like `load->upload()` is being inherited from `CI_Controller` class.  You really need to debug what is happening there. Most likely that method is just not getting the data it expects or something like that.  You really need you just debug up the call stack to find out where your problem is.